# "~/: Read only file system" on MacOS when attempting to export Pycharm settings

Tags: macos, pycharm

I am trying to export the `Pycharm` settings:

[image]

But why is  `Pycharm` not having permissions? Is there a way to grant them?

> Error Writing File
> Error writing settings
> java.nio.file.FileSystemException -: Read-only file system

[image]

I am on `Monterey 12.5.1`

Comment: It may not be expanding the `~` to your hope directory's path. Try explicitly using `/Users/whatever/Downloads/...`, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I've never had to do that before in fifty+ times over the years  of doing this across a couple dozen  machines.  But in any case i'll give that a go.  @GordonDavisson Expanding out *did* work.  Now given this was not needed in the past it is actually worthy of an answer. You can do or I will referencing your comment

Comment: @bad_coder  fair comment: so added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path had to be manually updated to the expansion of `~/Downloads` to my fully qualified home directory. Credit: comment by @GordonDavidson.

While this answer may seem simple/obvious it is not so much for those of us who have been using this feature without needing to make that manual substitution for many years - 14 years in my case.

- The IDE's "Open File" dialog did find this location and used that path. So it's at the least a mini bug that the path found is not acceptable
- I had never had to make the substitution in the past out of fifty+ times using this feature. I had presumed there were something "special" about `Monterey` security/permissions going on

Comment: Expanding `~` to the home directory path doesn't happen automatically in file access calls, it has to be done by some program. In the shell, expansion is handled by the shell itself (and there are some situations where it doesn't happen, like when `~` is quoted or coming from a variable). If it's worked before in that particular dialog, my guess would be that there's a bug in the current version of Pycharm that's somehow broken the expansion code.